# Elements going inside div tag when using context

Tags: django

My pages have a normal layout like so

[image]

When trying to include the calendar on the /calendar url everything seems to just squish under the calendar tab.

[image]

views.py

```
@login_required
def calendar(request):
    context={}  
    results = get_events(request)
    #context['results'] = results
    d = date.today()
    print(d)
    cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
    html_cal = cal.formatmonth(results, withyear=True)
    context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
    context['nmenu'] = 'calendar'
    editProfileForm = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    context['editProfileForm'] = editProfileForm
    if request.method=="POST":
        if 'editProfileForm' in request.POST:
            editProfileForm = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
            if editProfileForm.is_valid():
                editProfileForm.save()
                editProfileForm = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
                context['editProfileForm'] = editProfileForm
                context['is_post'] = False
                return render(request, "home.html", context)
            else:
                context['is_post'] = True
                context['editProfileForm'] = editProfileForm
                return render(request, "home.html", context)

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

calendar.html

```
{% block content %}
    <style>
        .calendar {
          width: 98%;
          margin: auto;
          font-size: 13px;
        }
      
        .calendar tr, .calendar td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
      
        .calendar th {
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 18px;
        }
      
        .calendar td {
          width: 200px;
          height: 150px;
          padding: 20px 0px 0px 5px;
        }
      
        .month {
          font-size: 25px;
        }
      
        .date {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      
        ul {
          height: 100%;
          padding: 0px 5px 0px 20px;
        }
    
    </style>
    
        <h1>Calendar</h1>
        <button>+</button>
        {{calendar}}
    
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- <ul>
        {% for result in results %}
            <li>{{result.start.date}}{% if result.end.date %}-{% endif%}{{result.end.date}}: {{result.summary}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul> -->
```

sidebar.html:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="col-md-3" style="float:left">
    <h1>Hi {{ user.username }}!</h1>
    <img class="avatar" src="{{user.get_profile_pic_url}}" >
    
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editProfile">+</button>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home"  href="{% url 'home' %}" >Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="calendar" href="calendar">Calendar</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="messages-tab" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" >Messages</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="messagesSend" href="messagesSend" >Send</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="messagesInbox" href="messagesInbox" >Inbox</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="documents"  href="documents" >Documents</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="medications" href="medications">Medications</a>
      </li>
      {% if request.user.is_staff %}
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <a class="nav-link" id="adminControls" href="adminControls" >Admin</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if request.user.is_staff is not True  and request.user.is_doctor is not True %}
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <a class="nav-link" id="bookAppointment"  href="bookAppointment" >Book Appointment</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="logout" href="{% url 'logout' %}" >Log out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9" style="float:right">
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="home" >
        {% include 'dashboard.html' %}
      </div>
      
      <div class="tab-pane" id="calendar" >
        {% include 'calendar.html' %}
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messagesSend" >
        {% include 'messagesSend.html' %}
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messagesInbox" >
        {% include 'messagesInbox.html' %}
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="documents" >
        {% include 'documents.html' %}
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="medications" >
        {% include 'medications.html' %}
      </div>
      {% if request.user.is_staff is not True  and request.user.is_doctor is not True  %}
        <div class="tab-pane" id="bookAppointment" >
          {% include 'bookAppointment.html' %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if request.user.is_staff %}
        <div class="tab-pane" id="adminControls" >
          {% include 'adminControls.html' %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>

  {% if nmenu %} 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("a#{{nmenu}}").addClass("active");
    $("div#{{nmenu}}").addClass("active");
  </script>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it seems somehow you are not closing the div of calendar. Maybe JS causing the problem?

Comment: Then you can try to print (`html_cal = cal.formatmonth(results, withyear=True)`) this to see if there is any unclosed element in the calendar.

Comment: Used print(mark_safe(html_cal)) and for some reason I had a missing </table>. Added it in and it works.